# Deploy custom python code (not standard ML models) to AWS Sagemaker Endpoint without Docker and ECR

Tags: amazon-sagemaker

I have a custom python-based model for recommendations. It's code that takes some input for a class and returns the recommendations via an API to the client. So, Flask and AWS EC2 work very well here.
Hence, I would like to use AWS Sagemaker instead, using the notebooks and further on to SM endpoint (with or without Flask doesn't matter).
I know the way via Docker-ECR but can't use it for some reasons.
And I failed to take a piece of python code from Sagemaker notebook and convert it into a Sagemaker model and deploy to EP without custom image, google was not of help either.
Also it's not a sklearn/huggingface or any of the standard ML frameworks either, just numpy/pandas stuff.
Could someone point me to the right doc please if this is possible anyway?

I expect Sagemaker EP to run with my custom code code and API that a client could request for the recommendation. I would like to take the code right from the Sagemaker notebook without Docker image and ECR and deploy it to the endpoint.

Answer (score 0):

SageMaker endpoints require a docker container.

As you correctly stated you usually would want to create your own container to host your custom code.

You could however, use one of the Framework containers such as TensorFlow and make use of the `handler` function to run your code and not load any model. https://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/stable/frameworks/tensorflow/using_tf.html#how-to-implement-the-pre-and-or-post-processing-handler-s

Ultimately, you do need to make use of a container. Either your can create your own one or make use of a pre-built one such as TensorFlow.

That being said do you need to host this code on a SageMaker endpoint? Could you not use Lambda for example?

Comment: Thanks @marc-karp! Sorry for the delay in commenting this. The Lambda is out of consideration as we use SM as a standard here. Will study handler more, not sure I fully understand the idea in the docs, so far failed to make the code work.